# node.js Websocket raspberry pi 4B ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, http, raspberry-pi

During this last days I'been trying to run a node.js web through raspberry pi 4 connected to a private network as a server running in **ubuntu server**. At first time it worked in my laptop with Windows 10.

The steps are:

Install:

```
yarn install
```

Run ReactJS Client:

```
yarn start
```

Run NodeJS Server (in a separate terminal window):

```
node server.js
```

And the code in the file server.js is:

```
const http = require('https');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const DeepSpeech = require('deepspeech');
const VAD = require('node-vad');

let DEEPSPEECH_MODEL = __dirname + '/deepspeech-0.6.0-models'; // path to deepspeech english model directory

let SILENCE_THRESHOLD = 200; // how many milliseconds of inactivity before processing the audio

const SERVER_PORT = 4000; // websocket server port

// const VAD_MODE = VAD.Mode.NORMAL;
// const VAD_MODE = VAD.Mode.LOW_BITRATE;
// const VAD_MODE = VAD.Mode.AGGRESSIVE;
const VAD_MODE = VAD.Mode.VERY_AGGRESSIVE;
const vad = new VAD(VAD_MODE);
```

etc.

And I get this error:

```
polling-xhr.js:267 
GET http://localhost:4000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N3VNHWo 
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Any idea?

Comment: I mean, it only works when I am running the server in the same computer I am trying it at the internet. When I run it in windors I can use it as localhost, but I get the error in other devices connected to the network.

Comment: Google console says the error comes from: ebug('xhr data %s', this.data);
    xhr.send(this.data);
  } catch (e) {

Comment: Can you add more on the code on how you register socket.io with http module? And where are the client code?

Comment: #mandaputtra The code is: https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech-examples/blob/r0.6/web_microphone_websocket/server.js

Comment: @ÁlvaroFernández I am facing the same issue, I am getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED while accessing nodes server(running on Raspberry Pi 4B) on my Mac. Did you find any solution. On localhost, server is working perfectly.